How do I keep cut flowers presentable for longer?
When my garden feels generous, I cut flowers from it and take them inside.
My normal procedure is to cut the branch I want, perhaps trim it further for aesthetics, and then place it in a vase of water.  I replace the water when it looks ugly, approximately weekly. When they are no longer attractive, they head to the compost.  Sometimes at this point there is obvious gelatinous life living on the submerged part of the branch.
Branches from the same azalea bush can last me anywhere from 1-5 weeks.  I have no idea what I'm doing differently for them!  The branches in the two pictures were both cut 12 days ago.  I think you can see the first one is doing better than the second.
What can I do to keep my cut flowers presentable for longer?



Cut the stems on an angle, add a little sugar to the water, then change the water every 2 days and recut a millimetre or two off the stems when you do so.
Cutting on an angle lets the flowers take up more water, the sugar acts as food, the water changes prevent bacteria and algae from building up in the water, and recutting keeps the exposed stem surface fresh  and free of decay and bacteria that might clog it.

Refrigerate them overnight, every night before, you go to bed, and take them out in the mornings. That's how florists keep them fresh and vibrant for long.
Additionally, you can prepare simple flower food at home. Mix 1 teaspoon sugar, 1 teaspoon of bleach and 2 teaspoons of lemon juice and stir well until the mix looks clear. Add this to the vase water immediately.
P.S. Prepare only the required amount.
Finally, no direct sunlight or fruits nearby.

I wouldn't have thought of that!  I am thinking of experimenting; if I ever do it I will include your recipe and  refrigeration as test methods.  My refrigerator is usually at 37°F / 3°C, would that be too cold?  And do you treat woody and herbaceous plants differently?
